# relation "app_model" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "app_model"

Tags: python, django, heroku, admin

I'm using Django and created a new model after deploying my app to Heroku, I get this error when I try to access my app's admin page.

Comment: Did you create a database ?

Comment: @Bea by making migrations and migrating? Yes.
Then I used git to add -A, commit -m, and push heroku master.

Comment: Could you share the model ?

Comment: class Post(models.Model): 
 caption = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
 image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
 author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

 def __str__(self):
  return self.caption

class Comment(models.Model):
 post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

 def __str__(self):
  return self.text